# Style laptop vs desktop

Tags: css, layout

Every time I change from desktop to laptop the styles on my page keep changing I'm at a loss why. I'm also getting the following warnings:

> W3C CSS Validator results for TextArea (CSS level 3)
>
> Sorry! We found the following errors (2) URI : TextArea
>   120   #container  Parse Error opacity=40) 226 #footer Parse Error
>   opacity=40)
>
> 166       Property -webkit-transform is an unknown vendor extension
>
> 167       Property -moz-transform is an unknown vendor extension
>
> 168       Property -o-transform is an unknown vendor extension
>
> 169       Property -webkit-transition-duration is an unknown vendor extension
>
> 170       Property -moz-transition-duration is an unknown vendor extension
>
> 171       Property -o-transition-duration is an unknown vendor extension

HTML

> ```
> <!DOCTYPE html> 
> <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
>   <head>
>       <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;  charset=ISO-8859-1"  />
>       <script type="text/javascript" src="js/scripts.js"  charset="utf-8"></script> 
>       <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css" />
>       <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="font-awesome-4.2.0/css/font-awesome.css" />
>       <title> Cake  </title>
>   </head>
>
>
> <body>
>
> <div id="header">
>   <a href="index.php"><img src="images/background.jpg" alt="HTML tags" /></a>
>
> </div>
>
>
> <div id="container">  
>
> <div id="navBar">
> <div class="nav-container">
>   <ul class="nav">
>     <li class="active">
>       <a href="index.php">
>         <span class="text"><i class="fa fa-home"></i>Home</span>
>       </a>
>     </li>
>     <li>
>       <a href="about.php">
>        <i class="fa fa-book"></i> <span class="text">&nbsp;About us</span>
>       </a>
>       </li>
>     <li>
>       <a href="contact.php">
>         <i class="fa fa-envelope-o"></i><span class="text">&nbsp;Contact us</span>
>       </a>
>       </li>
>     <li>
>       <a href="webDesign.php">
>         <i class="fa fa-cog"></i><span class="text">&nbsp;Web design</span>    
>       </a>
>     </li>
>     <li>
>       <a href="tutorials.php">
>       <i class="fa fa-graduation-cap"></i><span class="text">&nbsp;Tutorials</span>
>       </a>
>     </li>
>   </ul>
> </div>
> </div>
>   <div id="mainContent">      
>
>       <div id = "firstColumn">
>       <div class="spin">
>                   <a href="webDesign.php">    <i class="fa fa-html5"></i></a>
>       </div>
>           <br />
>           <p><a href="tutorials.php">Tutorials</a></p>
>       </div><!--End of first column-->
>   <div id = "secondColumn">
>                       <div class="spin">
>                   <a href="webDesign.php">    <i class="fa fa-at"></i></a>
>       </div>
>   </div><!--End of second column-->
>   <div id = "thirdColumn">
>                       <div class="spin">
>                   <a href="webDesign.php">    <i class="fa fa-html5"></i></a>
>       </div>
>   </div><!--End of third column-->
>   <div id = "fourthColumn">
>
>       <a href="tutorials.php">
>                           <div class="spin">
>                   <a href="webDesign.php">    <i class="fa fa-html5"></i></a>
>       </div>
>   </div><!--End of fourth column-->
>
>
>
> </div><!--mainContent-->  
>
>
> </div><!--Container div-->
> <div id="footer">
>    <a href="sitemap.php">Site map</a>
> </div><!--footer div-->       
> </body> 
> </html>
> ```
>
> CSS:
>
> ```
> @charset "UTF-8";
>
> *{
>   box-sizing: border-box;
>   margin:0px;
>   padding:0px;
>   font:  Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
>
> }
> body {
> background-image:url(../images/backgroundm.jpg);
> background-size: 100%;
>
> } 
>
>
>  /*Navigation bar style*/
> #navBar{
>
>
>       }
>
> .nav-container{
>   width:100%;
>   margin-top:10px;
>   transition: all 0.3s linear;
>   float:left;
>   margin-top:-4px;
> }
>
>
>
> .nav li{
>   float: left;
>   list-style: none;
>   background: linear-gradient(#292929, #242424);
> }
> .nav a {
>   border-top: 1px solid rgba(255,255,255,0.1);
>   border-bottom: 1px solid black;
>   text-decoration:none;
>   display:inline-block;
>   min-width: 190px;
>   height:100%;
>   line-height:30px;
>   color:#bbb;
>   text-transform: uppercase;
>   font-weight: bold;
>   padding: 5px 15px;
>   border-bottom:5px solid transparent;
>   letter-spacing:1px;
>   transition: all 0.3s linear;
>   text-align: center;
>    text-shadow: 2px 3px #000000;
> }
> .active a{
>   color: #B93632;
>   border-bottom:5px solid #B93632;
>   background-color: #1B1B1B;
>   outline:0;
>    text-shadow: 2px 3px #000000;
> }
> li:not(.active):hover a{
>   color: #eee;
>   border-bottom: 5px solid #FCFCFC;
>   background-color: #1B1B1B;
> }
>
>
> @media only screen and (max-width : 1024px){
>
>   .text{
>     display:none;
>   }
>
>   .nav-container , a{
>     width: 190px;
>
>   }
>
>   a:hover{
>     width:190px; 
>     z-index:1;
>     border-top: 1px solid rgba(255,255,255,0.1);
>     border-bottom: 1px solid black;
>     box-shadow: 0 0 1px 1px black;
>    text-shadow: 2px 3px #000000;
>   }
>
>   a:hover  .text {
>     display:block;
>     padding-left:30%;
>    text-shadow: 2px 3px #000000;
>   }
> }
> @media only screen and (max-width : 1024px){
>   .nav-container, a{ width:90px;}
>
> }
>
>
>
> /*Style header*/          
> #header{
>       width:1100px;
>       margin-left:auto;
>       margin-right:auto;
>       box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px #000000;
>       margin-bottom:2px;
>
> }     
>
> #header img{
>       width:100%;
> } 
>
> /*Style container*/       
> #container{
>       background-color:rgba(255,255,255,0.7);
>       filter: alpha(opacity=40); /* For IE8 and earlier */    
>       height:500px;
>       width:1100px;
>       margin-left:auto;
>       margin-right:auto;
>       box-shadow:10px 10px 5px #000000;
>
> }
>       /*style main content*/
> #mainContent{
>
>       width:100%;
>       margin-left:auto;
>       margin-right:auto;
>       margin-top:-5px;
> }
>
>
>
> /*first div starting from left of screen*/            
> #firstColumn{
>   width:230px;
>   height:250px;
>   float:left;
>   padding-left:65px;
>   margin-top:100px;
>   text-align: center;
>   font-size:24px;
> }
>
>
> #firstColumn img{
>   width:120px;
>   height:100px;
>   padding-left:20px;
>
> }
>
> .spin {
>   width: 240px;
>   height: 240px;
>   margin: 0 auto;
>   text-align: center;
> }
> .spin i {font-size: 240px; text-align: center; color:black;}
> .spin:hover {
>   -webkit-transform:rotate(360deg);
>     -moz-transform:rotate(360deg);
>     -o-transform:rotate(360deg);
>   -webkit-transition-duration: 0.8s;
>     -moz-transition-duration: 0.8s;
>     -o-transition-duration: 0.8s;
>     transition-duration: 0.8s;
> } 
>
>
> #secondColumn{
>   width:230px;
>   height:250px;
>   float:left;
>   padding-left:65px;
>   margin-top:100px;
>   text-align: center;
>   font-size:24px;
>
> } 
>
>
> #secondColumn img{
>   width:120px;
>   height:100px;
>   padding-left:20px;
>
>
> } 
>
> #thirdColumn{
>   width:230px;
>   height:250px;
>   float:left;
>   padding-left:65px;
>   margin-top:100px;
>   text-align: center;
>   font-size:24px;
> } 
>
>
>
> #fourthColumn {
>   width:230px;
>   height:250px;
>   float:left;
>   padding-left:65px;
>   margin-top:100px;
>   text-align: center;
>   font-size:24px;
> }
>
>
> /*style footer*/
> #footer{
>   width:1100px;
>   height:40px;
>   margin-left:auto;
>   margin-right:auto;
>   background-color:rgba(255,255,255,0.7);
>   filter: alpha(opacity=40); /* For IE8 and earlier */
>   border-top:solid 1px;
>   box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px #000000;
>
>   margin-top:0px;
>
> }
> ```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In all likelihood, it's because you're using media-queries.

```
     @media only screen and (max-width : 1024px){ }
```

A media query will alter the styles you present to the end-user based on your specifications. In this case the media query introduces new styles whenever the user is using only a screen (as opposed to print or tv media) and the max-width is 1024px.

As far as -webkit-transform, -moz-transform, -o-transform, these are vendor-specific (webkit browsers, Firefox and Opera) styles that affect the effects, speed and interval at which the element is affected. They're not loading or catching errors because they're not designed for Internet Explorer ($20 says that's what you're using, based on the errors).

Answer (score 0):

```
 /*Navigation bar style*/
#navBar{
        margin-top:-3px;
        height:50px;
        }
#navBar .nav-container{
    width:100%;
  margin-top:10px;
  transition: all 0.3s linear;
  float:left;
  margin-top:-4px;
  height:50px;
}
#navBar .nav li{
    float: left;
    list-style: none;
  background: linear-gradient(#292929, #242424);
  height:auto;
  width:220px;
}
#navBar .nav a {
  border-top: 1px solid rgba(255,255,255,0.1);
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
  text-decoration:none;
  display:inline-block;
  min-width: 190px;
  height:height:50px;
  line-height:30px;
  color:#bbb;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 5px 15px;
  border-bottom:5px solid transparent;
  letter-spacing:1px;
  transition: all 0.3s linear;
  text-align: center;
   text-shadow: 2px 3px #000000;
}
#navBar.active a{
  color: #B93632;
  border-bottom:5px solid #B93632;
  background-color: #1B1B1B;
  text-shadow: 2px 3px #000000;
}
#navBar li:not(.active):hover a{
  color: #eee;
  border-bottom: 5px solid #FCFCFC;
  background-color: #1B1B1B;

}
 #navBar .text{
    display:inline-block;
  }
#navBar  .nav-container  a{
    width: 220px;
    display:inline-block;
  }  
 #navBar a:hover{
    width:220px; 
    z-index:1;
    border-top: 1px solid rgba(255,255,255,0.1);
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
    box-shadow: 0 0 1px 1px black;
     text-shadow: 2px 3px #000000;
       border-bottom:5px solid #B93632;
  }
```